From 6.8.1 text inputs in editor's content are not editable
We have text inputs in content of editor, and they stopped to be editable after upgrade.
I created example reproducable issue here:
Codepen
  <form class="editcontent">
      Input: <input class="editcontent" value="test" />      
      </form>

Looks like bug in tinyMCE.
Could somebody help?
Thanks
Expect editable text inputs. For example checkboxes are editable.
